# My code is showing runtime error

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am trying to solve this HackerRank problem.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem

The general idea in this problem is that as Alice progresses up the leaderboard, I need to output her rank after each game.

My code is working against all test except for TestCase 6,7,8,9 and it's because it's getting RunTime Error.

This is my code:

```
from itertools import count
#Hackerrank Code
scores_count = int(input())
scores = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
alice_count = int(input())
alice = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
#My Code Starts from here
main_list = [sorted(scores+[i], reverse=True) for i in alice]
track = []
for sub in main_list:
    seen = {}
    c = count()
    next(c)
    ss = []
    for j in sub:
        try:
            ind = seen[j]
        except KeyError:
            ind = seen[j] = next(c)
        ss.append((j, ind))
    track.append(ss)
flicker = []
for x in track:
    gatter = dict(x)
    flicker.append(gatter)
trackstar = [d.get(key) for key, d in zip(alice, flicker)]
for m in trackstar:
    print(m)
```

I did like to know where's the flaw in my code that's showing Runtime Error and how can I fix it. I am using Python 3.x

Comment: Post the error (with full stacktrace).

Comment: But it's getting the Runtime Error in the website, not my computer

Comment: It could mean your code is using too much memory or time, and hackerrank's 'test runner' is killing your code.

Comment: @TomDalton Thanks, I will try to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid timeouts due too too long of a runtime, use a set of scores, not a list:

If you have `10**8` ppl all sitting on rank 3 with identical score you get very long lists - that are utterly not needed as they other `10**8-1` ppl sitting on the rank 3 as well do not contribute at all to Alices rank - but they make all the sorting and iterating take ***much*** longer

A very basic solution is:

```
input() # discard
scores = map(int,input().strip().split(' '))
input() # discard
alice = list(map(int,input().strip().split(' ')))

leaderboard = sorted(set(scores), reverse = True) # discard any identical scores before 
# sorting, sort by reverse so lowest score is last item in scores
l = len(leaderboard) # start with lowest score

# assumes alice never gets worse after playing games
for a in alice:
    while (l > 0) and (a >= leaderboard[l-1]):
        l -= 1 # climb the board
    print (l+1)
```

This will only ever look from the last score reached in the total list of scores, not starting at the lowest one for each of Alices part-scores.